# Can an Intel Wireless 7260 work as Access Point?

Tags: wireless, 13.10, intel-wireless, wireless-access-point

Is there any way to make an Intel Wireless 7260 (rev 73) to work as Access Point?

I couldn't find anything useful around. I'm on Ubuntu 13.10, and under `/lib/firmware` there are:

```
iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
```

I can do all the changes required (even installing an alpha Ubuntu), but I have no clues on what can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it is actually possible, using hostapd (and dnsmasq).

I've used a mix of the following links:

- https://arsprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/wi-fi-hotspot-on-ubuntu-13-10/
- https://nims11.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/using-hostapd-with-dnsmasq-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point-in-linux/

Answer (score 2):

Sharing eth0 with address 192.167.1.27/24 and dns server/router 192.167.1.1

On wlan with address 192.168.0.1/24

First, you must install dnsmask and hostapd by typing in terminal: `sudo apt-get install hostapd dnsmask`. After that, you must stop those services, by typing `sudo service hostapd stop`  and `sudo service dnsmasq stop`. Also prevent them from starting at startup:

```
sudo update-rc.d hostapd disable
sudo update-rc.d dnsmasq disable
```

my /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
server=192.167.1.1
interface=wlan0
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h
```

my hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
dump_file=/tmp/hostapd.dump
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
ssid=dellito
hw_mode=g
channel=1
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
rts_threshold=2347
fragm_threshold=2346
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wmm_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0
eapol_key_index_workaround=0
eap_server=0
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
```

Start:

```
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.0.1 up
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
service dnsmasq restart
iptables -t  nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

See what's going on / debug problems:

```
tcpdump -ni wlan0
```